# pthreads for Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pthreads, signals

I have some pretty old `Linux` based `C++` code that I need to port to a `Windows` platofrm:

```
sigset_t signalSet;
sigemptyset(&signalSet);
sigaddset(&signalSet, SIGALRM);
pthread_sigmask(SIG_BLOCK, &signalSet, 0);
```

But I cannot find the definition of `int pthread_sigmask(int how, const sigset_t *set, sigset_t *oldset)`. I have ported the `pthread.h` library to `Windows`. Is there an easy way to port this to `Windows`/`Visual C++`, or does anybody know where the definition of this function is located?

Comment: You seriously couldn't find http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_sigmask.3.html?

Comment: @kfsone - I found that document, I was hoping to find the function body itself instead of just a function prototype.

Comment: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/2a1bb4e64677b9abbc17173c79768ed494565047/libc/bionic/pthread_sigmask.cpp ? (first result in a search for pthread_sigmask source code) and http://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.23/sysdeps_2unix_2sysv_2linux_2sigprocmask_8c_source.html for sigprocmask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry about signals - SIGALRM does not exist in Windows anyways, and all you are doing is blocking *alarm* signal. You can just dummy this call out.

Comment: Signals are part of [ANSI C (C89)](http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt) § 4.7, [those defined by the standard do exist on Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx).

Comment: @JoeWatkins, perhaps you can show me SIGALRM in your own link?

Comment: Nope, I can't ... but you can retract the statement that signals *do not exist* on Windows ...

Comment: @JoeWatkins, ok, made a more specific statement.